# Switch default case not executing and causing infinite loop

Tags: c, switch-statement

When I input a character as an input, the default case of switch doesn't execute and the program loops infinitely.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
void create();
void display();
void search();
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* link;
};
struct node* head;
int main()
{
    int value;
    while (1) {
        printf("Enter Correct Choice :- \n");
        printf("Enter 1 to Create Linklist :- \n");
        printf("Enter 2 to Display Linklist :- \n");
        printf("Enter 3 to Search Linklist  :- \n");
        printf("Enter Your Choice Here _________ ");
        scanf(" %d", &value);
        switch (value) {
        case 1:
            create();
            break;
        case 2:
            display();
            break;
        case 3:
            search();
            break;
        default:
            printf("Error !! Wrong Choice :- \n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR-** Always check the return value of `scanf()` for success.

In case of a non-numeric character input, the format specifier `%d` does not find a match, and no input is consumed (i.e., the invalid input remains in the input buffer). Thus, the `switch` body executes, most likely it does not find a match with any existing `case` statement, so the default case statement(s) get executed, and control goes back to `while` loop.

Then, due to the presence of the *invalid* input in the buffer (and not getting consumed), the above phenomena keeps on repeating.

The major problem is, in case of `scanf()` failure, the value of variable `value` remains uninitialized and indeterminate. It does not construct a well-defined program.

Couple of things:

- Always initialize local variables.
- Always check for success of `scanf()` before using the returned value, if you have to use `scanf()`. For better use [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to take user input.
- In case of failure of input using `scanf()`, clean up the input buffer before trying to read next input.

Answer (score 0):

if a non valid integer is enter for `scanf(" %d", &value);` *value* is not set and the invalid input is not flush => *scanf* will never block nor update *value*

you need to check *scanf* returns 1 (you read 1 value) and if not to flush the invalid input for instance reading all the line

so you can replace

```
scanf(" %d", &value);
switch (value) {
...
}
```

by

```
if (scanf("%d", &value) != 1) {
  puts("invalid input");
  while ((value = getchar()) != '\n') {
    if (value == EOF) {
      puts("EOF, exit");
      exit(-1);
    }
  }
}
else {
  switch(value) {
  ...
  }
}
```

of course you can also manage the invalid input in your *default* case forcing an invalid value :

```
if (scanf("%d", &value) != 1) {
  while ((value = getchar()) != '\n') {
    if (value == EOF) {
      puts("EOF, exit");
      exit(-1);
    }
  }
  value = -1; /* any value except 1,2 or 3 */
}
switch(value) {
...
}
```

Out of that you have no option to stop the execution, you can do :

```
...
puts("Enter 4 to exit             :-);
...
switch (value) {
...
case 4:
   exit(0);
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `break` causes the program to exit the `switch case` but not the `while`. To wxit the while as well you should do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int value;
    int done = 0;
    while (!done) {
        printf("Enter Correct Choice :- \n");
        printf("Enter 1 to Create Linklist :- \n");
        printf("Enter 2 to Display Linklist :- \n");
        printf("Enter 3 to Search Linklist  :- \n");
        printf("Enter Your Choice Here _________ ");
        scanf(" %d", &value);
        switch (value) {
        case 1:
            printf("do stuff\n");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("do stuff\n");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("do stuff\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Error !! Wrong Choice :- \n");
            done = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here I used a variable initialized to 0 which indicates that the operation is not completed yet. When it's time to exit, the variable is set to 1, which causes the program to exit the while loop

Also, always remember to check the return value of `printf()`, to avoid possible errors

Answer (score 0):

There is no break condition for while().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
void create();
void display();
void search();
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* link;
};
struct node* head;
int main()
{
     int value = 1;
     while (value) {
        printf("Enter Correct Choice :- \n");
        printf("Enter 1 to Create Linklist :- \n");
        printf("Enter 2 to Display Linklist :- \n");
        printf("Enter 3 to Search Linklist  :- \n");
        printf("Enter 0 to exit  :- \n");
        printf("Enter Your Choice Here _________ ");
        scanf(" %d", &value);
        switch (value) {
        case 1:
            create();
            break;
        case 2:
            display();
            break;
        case 3:
            search();
            break;
        default:
            printf("Error !! Wrong Choice :- \n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive your intention is to run the program as long as "0" is not entered, but ter is no case for "0". also when we have scanf for %d and entering a "char" instead scanf will not read the char from buff. data on value will not get changed and it will keep printing existing data. (garbage if we enter invalid data first time itself, or any entered data.)

used fgets to read the input data, and do a scanf from buf, even when data is incorrect we are clearing the std input. so program will not get in to a infinite loop with scanf failure.

- initilised "value = 0"
- added case for "0".
- scanf is replaced with fget +sscanf

  ```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int main()
    {
        int value = 0;
        char buff[256] = {0};
        while (1) {
            value = -1;
            printf("Enter Correct Choice :- \n");
            printf("Enter 1 to Create Linklist :- \n");
            printf("Enter 2 to Display Linklist :- \n");
            printf("Enter 3 to Search Linklist  :- \n");
            printf("Enter Your Choice Here _________ ");
            fgets(buff, 255, stdin);
            sscanf(buff, "%d", &value);

            switch (value) {
            case 1:
                //create();
                printf("case : 1\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                //display();
                printf("case : 2\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                //search();
                printf("case : 3\n");
                break;
            case 0 :
                printf("case : 0 : Exiting program\n");
                return 0;
            default:
                printf("Error !! Wrong Choice :- %d\n", value);
                break;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
  ```